# What does start: 0.000000 mean in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

What does start: 0.000000 mean in ffmpeg ? when i converted a video it got changed to start 0.046440

> what does it mean ? 
>   Will it create any issue in output file ? 
>   How can i fix it ?

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Comment: ffmpeg -i filename.mp4   It will display all the video info..